# Adding Raise to Salary

Tags: java

I got the program running the way I want it.I am trying to make the program adds 2% raise to every employee's salary. My issue is that the program's output does not display the 2% raise.

Here is the output I get when I run the program..

```
Enter social security number:12345678
Enter salary2000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:12345677
Enter salary3000
Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:-1
        Social Security Number                       Salaries             Salary After Raise
                      12345678                    2000.000000                       0.000000
                      12345677                    3000.000000                       0.000000
```

The code..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Salaries {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Declaring variables
    int[] ssNumbers = new int [10];
    double[] salaries = new double [10];
    double[] nSalaries = new double [10];
    int c;

    c = inputData (ssNumbers, salaries); //calling input data method
    raise (salaries, c); // calling raise method
    output (ssNumbers, salaries, nSalaries); //calling output method
}
public static int inputData (int[]ssn, double[]sals){ // input method

    int c = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int ssNum;

    System.out.print("Enter social security number:");
    ssNum = input.nextInt();

    while (ssNum != -1) //using while loop.
    {
        ssn[c] =  ssNum;

        System.out.print("Enter salary");
        sals[c] = input.nextDouble(); //prompting user for input 
        c++;

        System.out.print("Please input next security numbers or -1 to quit:");
        ssNum = input.nextInt();  //prompting user for input 
    }
        return c;   
}
public static void raise (double[] salaries, int c) // raise method

{
    double[] salaryraise = new double [10];

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++ )
    salaryraise[i] = salaries[i]*.02;

}
public static void output (int[] ssNumbers, double[] salaries, double[] salaryraise ) //output method
{
    System.out.printf("%30s %30s %30s\n", "Social Security Number", "Salaries", "Salary After Raise");
    for (int i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++)

        //output
        System.out.printf("%30d %30f %30f\n", ssNumbers[i], salaries[i], salaryraise[i]);

    return;
}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a homework question, but I'll give ya a hint anyway.  From the looks of it, you are calling raise() which sets each salary to the 2%, not the salary + 2%.  Furthermore, you're not actually using those "raises" outside the function.

Comment: What does `void raise` do that affects anything outside of it?

Comment: I feel like a downvote here is unnecessary. It does seem homework related, but the OP did implement most of it and they just need help identifying a specific bug. They clearly put effort in though.

Answer (score 4):

In your `raise` method, you create a local array called `salaryraise`, and you assign the new numbers to it, but you do nothing with it, and it goes out of scope.

The array you do send to `output`, `nSalaries`, is declared, but it is never modified before it's sent to `output`.

Pass `nSalaries` as a second parameter to `raise`, and have `raise` assign values to that array instead of declaring a local array and assigning values to it.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code :

```
public static void raise (double[] salaries, int c) // raise method {
    double[] salaryraise = new double [10];

    // Here, you write to a new array and the original array isn't modified at all.
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
        salaryraise[i] = salaries[i]*.02;
    }
    // Change it for
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
        salaries[i] *= 1.02;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will modify the original `salaries` array, but those values need to be preserved so they can be printed in the `output` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't notice since the raise() method's signature doesn't offer any other way than the one I've mentioned.